# why RandomForestClassificationModel broadcasted to executores for every mini batch in spark streaming

Tags: spark-streaming, apache-spark-mllib, random-forest

## Setup:

1. Trained Random forest model in offline and stored in file system.
2. This model is loaded once at the start of spark-streaming application using Pipeline.load .
3. Predict function is called for every batch (model.transform(input_data_frame))

Observation: From the Spark-UI we can see that every task of this stage is spending most of the time(more than 95%) for task deserialization. Our assumption is every task is deserializing the models that loaded initially so we have tried broadcasting the models (broadcast variables is useful when caching the data in deserialized form is important but still it is showing high task deserialization time.

Spark standalone cluster details : spark version : 2.2.1 Executor core = 4 Executor Memory = 4 GB Total Executors = 24
#

### model size 45MB

spark kafka streaming job jar size 8 MB

1) why there is delay between this two steps ? what is happening between that steps?

attached is the spark kafka streaming log

18/04/15 03:21:23 INFO KafkaSource: GetBatch generating RDD of offset range: KafkaSourceRDDOffsetRange(Kafka_input_topic-0,242,242,Some(executor_xx.xxx.xx.110_2)), KafkaSourceRDDOffsetRange(Kafka_input_topic-1,239,239,Some(executor_xx.xxx.xx.107_0)), KafkaSourceRDDOffsetRange(Kafka_input_topic-2,241,241,Some(executor_xx.xxx.xx.102_3)), KafkaSourceRDDOffsetRange(Kafka_input_topic-3,238,239,Some(executor_xx.xxx.xx.138_4)), KafkaSourceRDDOffsetRange(Kafka_input_topic-4,240,240,Some(executor_xx.xxx.xx.137_1)), KafkaSourceRDDOffsetRange(Kafka_input_topic-5,242,242,Some(executor_xx.xxx.xx.111_5)) 18/04/15 03:21:24 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: start at App.java:106

2) why spark broad casting model to executor for every mini batch ?

18/04/15 03:21:31 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_92_piece0 in memory on xx.xxx.xx.137:44682 (size: 62.6 MB, free: 1942.0 MB) ##